# how mysql ordering strings?

Tags: mysql, encoding

```
SELECT IF('y' = 'i', 1, 2 ) -> 1 why?
```

Can I change encoding or somethint to get it right? and how to order strings like `irish` and `yes`

now field and table encoded in `utf8_lithuanian_ci`

so how to order list with these characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alphabetic sort is performed with respect of the **collation**, so you have to find which is better for you.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-general.html

Answer (score 1):

You can compare/order those strings using [BINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary) operator -

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY BINARY column;
```

From the reference - *The BINARY operator casts the string following it to a binary string. This is an easy way to force a column comparison to be done byte by byte rather than character by character.*

Answer (score 0):

Ordering works the same for strings as it does for integers. It performs an alphabetic sort.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column ASC
```